# What properties of a sheaf can be check at formal fibers?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $A$ be a Noetherian ring $X=SpecA$ and $Y$ a projective scheme over $A$. Let $f:Y \to X$ be the structure morphism. Let $\mathscr{F}$ be a coherent sheaf over $Y$. Suppose $x\in X$ is a closed point, let $\hat{Y}_x$ be the formal fibre of $Y$ along $x$ and $\hat{\mathscr{F}_x}$ be the pull back of the sheaf to the fibre

> My question is : What kind of properties of $\mathscr{F}$ can be check at each closed fibre? In particular, I am looking for proof that $\mathscr{F}$ is ample if $\hat{\mathscr{F}_x}$ is so for each closed point $x$ over the corresponding ring (or maybe it is wrong?).

I guess we need to make use of theorem of formal functions, and the properties desired should be explained using cohomology.